# Fortran compiler broken

Tags: fortran, macports, gfortran

I recently updated my operating system from OS X 10.8 to OS X 10.9. Most of the applications still worked after the update, but one of the applications that did not work was `g95` (my fortran compiler I use for class). I thought I was compiling faulty code until I tried compiling it on another machine. It seems as though the linker `ld` is missing a library that was not carried over in the update. The full error is produced on every compile time (as long as there are no syntax errors) `ld: library not found for -lcrt1.o`. Also, I do not specify this library, I just use the command `g95 file.f95 -o file` (with a simple script).

My attempts at fixing this mainly include uninstalling to reinstalling. Most recently I uninstalled the application will ALL dependences from MacPorts and re-installed the application with the dependencies just in case it would re-install the library it needs. The command I used to uninstall fortran is provided: `sudo port uninstall --follow-dependencies g95`. So how am I missing this supposedly crucial library? I wiped virtually everything it needs and reinstalled all dependences for this reinstall.

Comment: If you can't figure this out you could use gfortran from MacPorts by installing packages gcc47 or gcc48.

Comment: @M.S.B. Thanks for responding. I just tried to install `gcc48` on MacPorts and got back `fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]` in the logs. I'll try `gcc47` now.

Comment: @M.S.B. Thank you so much! After installing gcc47 the compiler is back. It looks that that gcc4X was required but was somehow missing from the MacPorts dependences for `g95`. You can post the answer so I can properly give you credit for your help.

Comment: BTW `g95 != gfortran`.

Comment: @patrickvacek Thanks I thought `g95 == gfortran95`. It looks like that is not true.

Comment: Yeah, there was some drama there or something, but at any rate, `gfortran` originally was forked from `g95`. Also see here: http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/TheOtherGCCBasedFortranCompiler