# g95 ld: library not found for -lcrt1.o

Tags: macos, fortran

I am trying to compile Fortran code using g95 in Mac OSX 9 on a Macbook Pro machine.

The compiler gives the following error

```
ld: library not found for -lcrt1.o
```

I've tried installing gcc47 as suggested in previous question [Fortran compiler broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580324/fortran-compiler-broken) but this doesn't work.

Comment: Apparently I solved this particular problem by installing the command line tools as per in this webpage https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/installing-intel-compilers-for-os-x-pre-requisite-xcode-command-line-tools. However, I know have the following issue g95 parkind.f90 
ld: warning: -macosx_version_min not specified, assuming 10.6
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_MAIN_", referenced from:
      _main in libf95.a(main.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Comment: OK the issue was solved compiling the code using g95 -c option as shown in this thread https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/issues/271

Answer (score 1):

Just using the -c argument is not ideal, as then you just get the object file, and not the executable.

I had the exact same problem, and ended up solving it by installing the additional command line tools after having installed xcode from the App Store (and also having remembered to open it and agreed to its terms and conditions).

Type in the command line: 
`xcode-select --install`

It seems that this installs the file that was missing.