# Xcode & OpenFrameworks IOS apps will not run

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, openframeworks

I can’t seem to get the example IOS Apps in OF working on Ipad. They only work in the Ipad simulator. I downloaded the specific IOS version of OF for Xcode.

Each time I get an error, then it seems that if change one thing recommended by the error readout I get another completely different error. At the moment the error looks like this:

[image]

Is anyone aware of tutorials online where I can see clearly the steps involved in the process of loading very simple OF app to ipad? I may have messed up in the developer bit.

I found a user with a similar conundrum here:
[g95 ld: library not found for -lcrt1.o](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23666762/g95-ld-library-not-found-for-lcrt1-o)

I followed the recommendations but either nothing worked or I didn't understand how to implement.

I’d really appreciate any help at all.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `crt1.o` for iOS. This file contains the start symbols on some systems. You should search for `crt1.3.1.o` in the build settings, and delete this flag or the `crt1.3.1.o` from the settings.

Answer (score 0):

This was a symptom of a settings issue in Xcode and noting related to changing code, as it turns out.

Comment: Can you share the answere?